# How to apply styles for `gt` table in the rmarkdown

Tags: r, markdown

I have a `rmarkdown` which contains table built using `gt` package. When I run the code chunk for generating table it prints in the desired format but in the word output. It doesn't get that format.

Sample code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
date: "2023-09-11"
---
```

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)
```

### R Markdown

```
data <- data.frame("Column 1" = c(1,2,4),
          "Column 2" = c(2,5,6),check.names = FALSE)


data %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = cell_text(weight = "bold"),
    locations = cells_body(
      rows = 1
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_options(column_labels.hidden = TRUE,table.font.size = "50px ",
               data_row.padding = px(20))
```

The bold style is shown in the final word output, but neither the font size though nor the padding applied to the  final word document.

Comment: I believe this a known limitation with non-html output such as Word. If you change your preamble call to html_document, you will see the tab_options applied to the output

Comment: @SusanSwitzer Yes, in the html output. It works as expected.

Comment: How can I solve this in the case of word or atleast pdf.